# Can I say is lossy compression to discard data having a way to recover it?

Tags: data-compression

I'm working on a compression algorithm for a specific kind of data. I have found a way to discard (important) parts of the data during compression as I have also found a way to recover the missing parts during decompression.

The decompression algorithm most of the times will infer the data equal to the discarded one. However, in punctual cases, it will infer similar data that works just as well as the original.

So my question is: **Can I claim that my algorithm is lossy?**

Comment: A compression algorithm is *lossy* if you cannot always recover the original uncompressed data. If this is the case for your algorithm, then it is lossy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, in punctual cases, it will infer *similar* data that works just as well as the original.

From this I would conclude it is [lossy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) because it is similar data, rather than [lossless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression), which would be a perfect reconstruction.

That being said, I'm not entirely what you mean by "data that *works* just as well", but if the data works **exactly** how the original data would *work*, for your use case it might be considered lossless because the information you need and compress is not lost. You must be careful to specify that the compression of the information you wish to recover is lossless, but the compression of the data as a whole is lossy.

As example, if my goal is to save (using compression) simple arithmetic equations to later determine if they are odd or even. I might compress $f = 4 + 3 + 8 +1$ into the number of even ($e$) and odd ($o$) terms it has: $ C(f) = 2e2o$. This is clearly lossy, I can't perfectly reconstruct which terms created $f$, but for my purposes I can clearly determine whether it is odd or even after compression. Even further I could reconstruct *similar* data (as you stated) that works just as well as the original, for my purposes.